# Вывод инфы из массива

Tags: php, массивы, инспекция-кода

У меня есть массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "без заголовка" {
            [1] => "без заголовка" {
            [2] => "без заголовка" {
        )

    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => без заголовка
            [1] => без заголовка
            [2] => без заголовка
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => без заголовка
            [1] => без заголовка
            [2] => без заголовка
        )

    [content] => Array
        (
            [0] => тестовый комментарий 1
            [1] => тестовый комментарий 2
            [2] => тестовый комментарий 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => тестовый комментарий 1
            [1] => тестовый комментарий 2
            [2] => тестовый комментарий 3
        )

    [date_2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12:05, 07.04.2017
            [1] => 12:05, 07.04.2017
            [2] => 12:05, 07.04.2017
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12:05, 07.04.2017
            [1] => 12:05, 07.04.2017
            [2] => 12:05, 07.04.2017
        )

    [date_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12:00, 07.04.2017
            [1] => 12:00, 07.04.2017
            [2] => 12:00, 07.04.2017
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12:00, 07.04.2017
            [1] => 12:00, 07.04.2017
            [2] => 12:00, 07.04.2017
        )

)
```

И код который выводит из него всю инфу по очереди, в смысле как то так:

```
без заголовка
12:00, 07.04.2017
12:05, 07.04.2017
тестовый комментарий 1
без заголовка
12:00, 07.04.2017
12:05, 07.04.2017
тестовый комментарий 2
без заголовка
12:00, 07.04.2017
12:05, 07.04.2017
тестовый комментарий 3
```

Код для его обработки:

```
$comment_i = 0;

foreach($comments_arr['title'] as $key => $val) {
    foreach($comments_arr['title'] as $key => $val) {
        if ($key == $comment_i) {
            $title = $val;
        }
    }
    foreach($comments_arr['date_1'] as $key => $val) {
        if ($key == $comment_i) {
            $date_1 = $val;
        }
    }
    foreach($comments_arr['date_2'] as $key => $val) {
        if ($key == $comment_i) {
            $date_2 = $val;
        }
    }
    foreach($comments_arr['content'] as $key => $val) {
        if ($key == $comment_i) {
            $content = $val;
        }
    }

    echo $title . '<br>';
    echo $date_1 . '<br>';
    echo $date_2 . '<br>';
    echo $content . '<br>';

    $comment_i++;
}
```

Можно ли его упростить? Потому что сейчас это реализовано весьма неоптимально, на мой взгляд.

---

**Что получилось:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => без заголовка
            [username] => username_1
            [content] => тестовый комментарий 1
            [date_2] => 12:05, 7 апреля 2017
            [date_1] => 12:00, 7 апреля 2017
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => без заголовка
            [username] => username_2
            [content] => тестовый комментарий 2
            [date_2] => 12:05, 7 апреля 2017
            [date_1] => 12:00, 7 апреля 2017
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => без заголовка
            [username] => username_3
            [content] => тестовый комментарий 3
            [date_2] => 12:05, 7 апреля 2017
            [date_1] => 12:00, 7 апреля 2017
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => test name
            [username] => test_user
            [content] => test content
            [date_2] => 15:34, 08 апреля 2017
            [date_1] => 15:31, 08 апреля 2017
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => test name
            [username] => test_user
            [content] => test content
            [date_2] => 15:34, 08 апреля 2017
            [date_1] => 15:31, 08 апреля 2017
        )

)
```

---

```
    foreach ($comments_arr_raw as $key => $value) {
        if (is_int($key)) {
            unset($comments_arr_raw[$key]);
        }
    }
    foreach($comments_arr_raw as $key => $a){
        foreach($a as $k => $v){
            $comments_arr[$k][$key] = $v;
        }
    }

    $comment_i = 0;
    foreach($comments_arr as $comment) {
        echo '<tr><td style="padding-left: 0px;">';
        echo '<img src="/i/comment.gif" width="11" height="13" border="0" align="left" style="margin-right: 8px;">';
        echo '<a href="/view_comments/45987"><b>' . $comment['title'] . '</b></a>';
        echo '<br>';
        echo '<a href="/user/chupacabras">' . $comment['username'] . '</a>, <small>' . $comment['date_1'] . '<span class="modify_time">, ' . $comment['date_2'] . '</span></small>';
        echo '<p>' . $comment['content'] . '</p>';
//      echo '<p><span class="r_button_small"><a href="/edit?original_id=45987&link_id=2">ответить</a></span></p>';

        echo '</td></tr>';

        $comment_i++;
    }
```

Comment: @Pyramidhead Толи я тупой, то что, но как мне здесь поможет функция, для проверки существования ключа массива?

Comment: Избавит от бестолкового перебора элементов с проверкой `($key == $comment_i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Вариант 1.** Сделать транспонирование массива (поменять ключи первого и второго уровня). Возможно даже с удалением значений с числовыми ключами. Я так вижу, что у вас исходный массив `$comments_arr`) имеет дублирующую информацию. Например `$comments_arr['title']` то же самое что и `$comments_arr[0]`, `$comments_arr['content']` - `$comments_arr[1]` и т. д. Получим более удобный  массив с такой структурой:

```
$comments_arr = [
    [
        'title' => '...',
        'content' => '...',
        'date_1' => '...',
        ...
    ],
    [
        'title' => '...',
        'content' => '...',
        'date_1' => '...',
        ...
    ],
    ...
]
```

С таким массивом код будет более наглядным и понятным:

```
foreach ($comments_arr as $comment) {
    echo $comment['title'] . '<br>';
    echo $comment['date_1'] . '<br>';
    echo $comment['date_2'] . '<br>';
    echo $comment['content'] . '<br>';
}
```

Конечно нужно понимать, что  переработка массива - это дополнительное время, поэтому такой путь это повышение наглядности с жертвой оптимизации.

**Вариант 2.** Оставить массив как он есть, но проверять на наличие всех нужных полей (на всякий случай). При появлении отсутствующих возможно будет полезно записывать предупреждение в лог.

```
foreach($comments_arr['title'] as $key => $val) {
    if (!isset(
        $comments_arr['content'][$key],
        $comments_arr['date_1'][$key],
        $comments_arr['date_2'][$key]
    )) {
        // пропускаем записи, у которых нету какого-то из "полей"
        continue; 
    }
    echo $val . '<br>';
    echo $comments_arr['date_1'][$key] . '<br>';
    echo $comments_arr['date_2'][$key] . '<br>';
    echo $comments_arr['content'][$key] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, вариант с транспорированием массива помог. Пришлось искать инфу как это делать, но в целом это было не долго и результатом я доволен!